# Convert NSArray containing NSString to NSString

Tags: objective-c, ios

So, I have an NSArray containing NSString. How can I convert the NSArray to NSString separating them by new line.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [componentsJoinedByString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-BABDECEE):

```
NSString *combinedString = [myArray componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];
```

Comment: Thanks for some reason it was not showing up in intellisense! Problem solved!